# Comma Delimiting Names with Apostrophes

Tags: sql, t-sql

This is a T-SQL question.

I have a select statement where i take a list of cities and comma delimit them, then put them into a temp table.  However, one of my cities is Couer D'Alene, which has an apostrophe in its name, and SQL is not liking that - no results are returned.  How can I modify this to accept city names with apostrophes?  Thanks!

```
Declare @vCity varchar(1000)

Select @vCity= ',' + @vCity+ ','

create table #Cities
(
    cityName varchar (1000)
)

Insert Into #Cities
Select  cityName
From cityTable
Where  @vCity Like  '%,' + cityName + ',%'
Group By cityName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `'` with another `'`:`''`

Easiest way is the `REPLACE` function:

```
Select @vCity= ',' + REPLACE(@vCity,'''', '''''' ) + ','
```

All the extra `'` are escaping several layers deep.

Answer (score 0):

```
select QUOTENAME( cityName, '''' ) ...
```